# Integrating an unknown function

Tags: integration

I was wondering how you solve an integral with an unknown function in it such as:
 $\int 4x(t)^3 dt$ ?

Do I integrate the outside then the inside, as in $4 \cdot \frac14 \cdot x(t)^4 \cdot t = x(t)^4 \cdot t$?

Comment: This become $\int4x(t)^3dt=4\int x(t)^3dt$, but you dont have in general that $\int x(t)^3dt=\frac{x(t)^4}{4}t$, you can see this by seting $x(t)=t$

Answer (score 2):

You cannot do this. Jus to prove it, assume that your result $ x(t)^4*t$ is correct and compute its derivative. What you have then is $\frac{d}{dt}x(t)^4*t=4 t x(t)^3 x'(t)+x(t)^4$ which does not have much to do with $4x(t)^3$.

If the derivartives of $x(t)$ are simpler and simpler, probably the best would be integration by parts. Let $$I=\int 4*x(t)^3 dt=4\int x(t)^3 dt=4J$$ and start using $u=x(t)^3$, $v'=dt$ so $u'=3x(t)^2 x'(t) dt$, $v=t$ So, $$J=\int x(t)^3 dt=t x(t)^3-3\int t x(t)^2 x'(t)dt$$ and repeat for the last antiderivative.