# How do I integrate an unknown function of a variable e.g. $a(t)$?

Tags: calculus, integration, functions

How would I integrate equations of the following form:

$$\frac{d a(t)}{dt}=ka(t)$$

*where $k$ is constant.*

I have the feeling that this is quite simple, but I seem to be stuck.

My initial thought was that I could do:

$$a(t) da(t) = k dt \iff  \frac{a^2(t)}{2} = kt + c $$

But for some reason I don't think this is right.
Should I instead do integration by parts as done in [Integrating an unknown function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/930482/integrating-an-unknown-function)?

Comment: $\frac{da(t)}{a(t)}=k\,dt$ could be better

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is quite an infamous differential equation, one of the basic ones you learn in calculus courses. Use separation of variables.
$$
\frac{a(t)}{dt} = ka(t) \implies \frac{da(t)}{a(t)}= kdt \implies \int \frac{da(t)}{a(t)}=\int k dt $$
and so on.

Comment: I multiplied instead of dividing out of pure distraction. Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: @user7077252 No problem! Accept the answer if it was what you were looking for :)

Comment: Only allowed to do so in a minute's time

Answer (score 2):

The general solution to this ODE is $a(t) = Be^{kt}$, $B \in \Bbb{R}$. Note that you made an algebraic error. On the LHS, it should be $\dfrac{da}{a}$, so upon integration you should get $\ln|a| = kt +c$.